# NASM Boot Loader strange behavior

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

I'm trying  to write a boot loader but none of my experiments didn’t worked until I found this question: [Why doesn't this boot loader code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699422/why-this-boot-loader-doesnt-working)

I had simplified this program to only write a char to screen.

```
[ORG 0x7C00]
[BITS 16]

realstart:
    jmp start
    nop


start:
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    xor bx,bx
    mov ah, 0x0e
print:
    mov al, "A"
    int 0x10
end:    
    cli
    hlt  

    times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

It compiles fine, but in the [objdump](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y31/bannyy/NASM%20problem/normal-dump.png) there isn’t any  int 0x10 command.

If I leave strings ([this file](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y31/bannyy/NASM%20problem/str-source.png)) it all works fine.

Where's the catch?

(Compiling with NASM 2.08.02-1 on Cygwin Win7 SP1)

Comment: I'm compiling with:

    nasm -O0 -f bin bootLoader.asm -o bootLoader.bin

Comment: Post objdump dump. Compiled with FASM and dumped with ndisasm and the int 10h is there.

Comment: I have uploaded screen shots: http://s2.photobucket.com/albums/y31/bannyy/NASM%20problem/   Im using Win7 SP1, Cygwin, NASM.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior, since the `55 AA` isn't placed properly multiple things seem to have gone wrong. Could you update your question with exactly the file that gives the wrong output?

Comment: That doesn't seem right at all, are you using the latest version?

Comment: Today I reinstalled to latest nasm in cygwin (2.08.02-1), but problem is still there. The file with wrong output is http://s2.photobucket.com/albums/y31/bannyy/NASM%20problem/?action=view&current=normal-source.png

Comment: Edit the question with the code + output as text instead. No one feels like typing in the code from a screen shot.

Comment: You file assembles fine with nasm 2.09.08 on linux x86_64 and boots to show an 'A' with qemu.

Comment: yes, I tried it by my self and it compiled fine on ubuntu. There must be something wrong with cygwin and/or nasm.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be nothing wrong with the code. It would be very strange if disassembling the code with ndisasm yields a result with int 0x10 missing. So I guess you talk about dumping the code in runtime. The bootsector normally contains a boot record right after the jump instruction (which tells the bootloader about the size of the media and such). Perhaps the BIOS is medling with what it thinks is a boot record for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
Bits 16
org 0x7c00
start:
xor ax,ax
mov ah,0x0E
mov al,'A'
int 10h
mov al,10h
int 16h
int 19h
hlt
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Try This Code.If It Doesn't Work,make me know.